# OrientDB Studio - get string value from UPDATE .. UPSERT RETURN BEFORE

Tags: graph, orientdb

The class `co` has a property `idLastPost STRING`. I want to use the `@rid` stored in `idLastPost` in an other query, but I can not access the result from the `UPDATE ... BEFORE` as a string.

**Code:**

```
var db = orient.getGraph();
var idLastPost=db.command('sql',
    'UPDATE co SET idLastPost=#12:1 UPSERT RETURN BEFORE @this.idLastPost WHERE @rid=#15:1'
);    
db.command('sql','CREATE edge nextPost FROM '+idLastPost+' TO #16:1);
```

When I `return idLastPost` in Orient Studio after the first query, I get the `@rid` as

```
[{
    "@type": "d",
    "@version": 0,
    "value": "#12:2"
}]
```

But I can not use this result in the second command. The occurring parsing error reveals, that `idLastPost` is interpreted as `[Ljava.lang.Object;@61ee4a70`. Apparently `idLastPost` is a Java array.

I have already tried to replace `idLastPost` in the second query with:

- idLastPost[0]
- idLastPost[0].value
- idLastPost.value
- idLastPost.getValue()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.command('sql','CREATE edge nextPost FROM '+idLastPost[0].getProperty("value")+' TO #16:1);
```